# Why do the $U$ and $V^T$ have to be orthogonal matrix in SVD ? is it a definition or a theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, singular-values

$M=U\Sigma V^T$,and $U$ and $V$ are both orthogonal matrix ,that is ,$V^T=V^{-1}$, and $U^T=U^{-1}$

Why do the $U$ and $V^T$ have to be orthogonal matrix  in SVD ? is it a definition or a theorem?if it is a theorem,can anyone prove it?

Comment: For a proof of SVD, you may consult any numerical linear textbook, or any linear algebra textbook that emphasises applications.

Comment: @user1551 so you mean this is a theorem,not a definition?

Comment: It's both. A decomposition $M=U\Sigma V^T$ (when $M$ is real) is called a singular value decomposition if $U$ and $V$ are real orthogonal and $\Sigma$ is a nonnegative (perhaps rectangular because $M$ can be rectangular) diagonal matrix. This is a definition. However, the existence of a SVD for any *given* real matrix $M$ is a theorem.

Comment: why?aren't they the same?

Comment: Because you say A decomposition $M=UΣV^T$.....is a definition,however,the existence of a SVD for any given real matrix M is a theorem.but these two M should be the same,why will the " real matrix M " affect a definition become a theorem?

Comment: A decomposition $A=PDP^{-1}$ is called an eigendecomposition of $A$ if $P$ is nonsingular and $D$ is diagonal. This is a definition. However, not every matrix has an eigendecomposition. E.g. $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ has none. The existence or non-existence of a matrix decomposition is something that you need to prove. It's the same when we are talking about SVD. It turns out that unlike eigendecomposition, every matrix has a SVD.

Comment: As for realness, if $A$ is non-real, its SVD takes the form of $U\Sigma V^\ast$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices. When $A$ is real, $U$ and $V$ can be taken to be real, and hence they become orthogonal, but in general, $U$ and $V$ are merely unitary.

Comment: oh i see,you misunderstand it,the $M=UΣV^T$ is SVD,there is no eigendecomposition